# Knowledge articles related list on a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list, knowledge

I have a Visualforce page where I have few fields coming from Cases. I need to have Knowledge Articles related list on the page for the Case.

I cannot use Apex:detail tag as I need only specific fields on the page to be displayed.

Any solution for the above scenario??

Thanks in advance
Raj

Comment: Did you already try something ? you can query data and use a number of visualforce tags to display data the way you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Case standard controller you should simply be able to use an `apex:relatedList` tag on your Visualforce page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:relatedList list="CaseArticles"/>
</apex:page>
```

If you're not using the standard controller then you'll have to define the subject attribute for this to work.

Controller:

```
public class MyController 
{
    private final Case aCase;

    public MyController() {
        aCase = [SELECT Id FROM Case 
                   WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

    public Case getCase() 
    {
        return aCase;
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:relatedList subject="{!Case}" list="CaseArticles"/>
</apex:page>
```

See here for more information on the `apex:relatedList` tag:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm